# How correctly describe a proto file?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

Let's say we want to create such table in the future:

```
CREATE TABLE CITY (
    CITY_ID INT8 UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    FOUNDATION_DATE TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    CITY_NAME VARCHAR NULL,
    CITY_TYPE VARCHAR DEFAULT 'Unknown',
    INVISIBLE BOOL NULL
);
```

I am trying to create a `proto` file that will match and not conflict with this table structure. But unfortunately, I got confused and need some help. I found out from the official documentation that `proto3` doesn't have the option to specify required and optional fields in the `message`. I also can't figure out how to specify default values in fields.

At this point I have described the following `city.proto` file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

message City {
    google.protobuf.UInt64Value city_id = 1;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp foundation_date = 1;
    google.protobuf.StringValue city_name = 3;
    google.protobuf.StringValue city_type = 4;
    google.protobuf.BoolValue invisible = 5;
}
```

After generating go code via the `protoc` compiler, we usually get a strongly typed `struct`. With the help of [GORM](https://gorm.io/) package, I want to make automigration and create a table based on this struct.

In my project, I use `go modules`.

I use such command to generate go code:

```
protoc proto/city.proto -I. -I%GOPATH%/src --go_out=plugins=grpc:proto/city
```

Unfortunately, the command causes the following error:

```
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: plugins are not supported; use 'protoc --go-grpc_out=...' to generate gRPC
```

**go version**:

```
go version go1.12.9 windows/amd64
```

**protoc --version**:

```
libprotoc 3.11.4
```

**QUESTION**:

How to correctly describe the proto file for our table and how to generate go code correctly?

Comment: change this `--go_out=plugins=grpc` to this `--go-grpc_out=`

Comment: I've already tried this. Unfortunately, I see the following error: `--go-grpc_out: protoc-gen-go-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.`. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we need to wait for gRPC folks to provide it. It’s in the release notes (https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-go/releases/tag/v1.20.0#v1.20-grpc-support) that it’s not supported.

But I have been using https://github.com/golang/protobuf/releases/tag/v1.4.0-rc.2 and this new `google.goolang.org/protobuf V1.20.0` together. It generates a `protobuf/grpc` Go code that implements e.g. `ProtoReflect` method and actually uses this new reflect API.

Comment: Thank you for the information. In fact, I am confused with all these dependencies. Right now I use [1.4.0](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/releases/tag/v1.4.0) version of `github.com/golang/protobuf` which was published after the pre-release version which you mentioned in your post. Are there any alternatives to describe the proto file in more detail? I found such third-party implementation [github.com/gogo/protobuf](https://github.com/gogo/protobuf) but I'm not sure if I should use it.

Comment: Yeah the tooling is a little less than awesome right now. It's usable, but kinda' complicated to set up

Comment: I was able to generate go code using the `github.com/gogo/protobuf` package using the command: `protoc -I. -I%GOPATH%/src --gofast_out=plugins=grpc:. proto/city.proto`. But no one has answered my main question yet. How much does my proto file fully reflect the table structure I specified in the post? What do you think about this?